# is there a replacement of shared_memory_object in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am trying to convert a c++ code to `c++11` style and I would like to stop using some boost related libraries. I know `c++11` borrowed a lot of concepts from boost.  Is there a replacement of `shared_memory_object` in `c++11`?

Comment: See [relevant-boost-features-vs-c11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851670/relevant-boost-features-vs-c11) for what is already included and planned to be in c++11/14/17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no notion of "Shared memory" in the standard. And thus no facilities to work with it.