# boost: replace basic classes to std one?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

As I see many std classes from `c++11` take their origin from `boost` library. So boost library has array, mutex, shared_ptr, unique_ptr, function etc, and std analogs with almost the same interface and semantics. And I wonder, why not to have build mode for boost,
where I can add compiler flag like `-DUSE_CXX11_CLASSES`,
and boost low level stuff become just `typedef` to `std` one?

So, for example, if I use `boost:program_options` and `c++11`,
I don't have in my program many duplicates.

I mean, yes it is good to have boost low level classes, for compilers that not support `c++11`, but why not, for compilers, which support `c++11` use already available stuff?

Comment: The boost versions generally have additional functionality and plumbing which the boost library itself relies on, the templates and classes aren't necessarily compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some libraries use c++11 classes automatically when detected. It depends on the library author.

There is no such general compilation flag you can use.

Comment: Thanks, can you point out one example, please? So I can use this example and create pull request at least for program_options.

Comment: For one, Spirit X3 uses it. Boost fusion supports it (`fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp`). Boost ASIO supports `std::chrono` instead of `boost::chrono` (`BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO`) etc. etc.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851670/which-boost-features-overlap-with-c11/8852558#8852558