# Boost ASSIGN syntact to overload += to initialize vectors and add values

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class vector_inserter{
public:
    std::vector<T> v;
    vector_inserter(std::vector<T>& v):v(v){}
    vector_inserter& operator,(const T& val){v.push_back(val);return *this;}
};
template <class T> vector_inserter<T> operator+=(std::vector<T>& v,const T& x)
{
    return vector_inserter<T>(v),x;
}

int main()
{
vector_inserter<int> t+=1,2,3,

}
```

I came across this code in stack overflow, i am still trying to understand how it works, i try to compile the above code but i get errors as expected initializer be +=

Is there any good way to overload operators for Vector operation like {}, (), +=?

Comment: You can't use the `operator+=()` for variable initialization. And the syntax `vector_inserter<int> t+=1,2,3,` would be totally wrong anyways, even for a valid initializer overload.

Comment: What does your question actually have to do with [tag:boost] BTW?

Comment: Boost offers the += operator overloading.

Comment: But you're not using boost anywhere in your code example?

Comment: example vector<Int > t;t+=1,2,3;

Comment: And how's that related to boost please?

Comment: I am trying to implement boost like overloading to my own vector class

Comment: And how is that actually implemented in boost? Did you have a look at it?

Comment: Please check the previous post. They have overloaded += operator to put the numbers in to vectors

Comment: Which previous post? I can't spot any link in your question.

Comment: Using boost we can do something like this. vector<Int > t;  t+=1,2,3; i am trying to overload same thing.

Comment: This whole thing is dodgy because the template `operator+=` can never be found by ADL

Comment: #include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <vector>

Answer (score 0):

Boost Assign is one of the few parts of Boost that I really consider mostly  obsolete (see [Which Boost features overlap with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851670/which-boost-features-overlap-with-c11))

Firstly, here's a (much) more general version of your code fixed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8e9f8a240a10b8)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

template <class C> struct inserter {
    C& c;
    template <typename T>
    inserter& operator,(const T& val){ c.insert(c.end(), val); return *this; }
};

template <typename C, typename V = typename C::value_type> inserter<C> operator+=(C& c, const V& x) {
    return inserter<C>{c}, x;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> t;
    t += 1,2,3;

    std::list<int> l;
    l += 1,2,3;

    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m += std::make_pair(1, "one"), std::make_pair(2, "two"), std::make_pair(3, "three");
}
```

Note how it works for other types.

Here's how you'd write similar things in /just/ c++11:

```
std::vector<int> t {4,5,6};
t.insert(t.end(), {1,2,3});
t.assign({1,2,3});
```

Comment: I found easy way. Vector& operator+=(const T &val){t.push_back(val);return *this;}
 Vector& operator,(const T &val){t.push_back(val);return *this;}