# Why do I need Boost.SmartPtr for the C++ compiler that supports C++11 and later?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, smart-pointers

The boost C++ library is a famous sandbox for the language and Standard Library features that absorbed with each new version of the Standard C++. However boost components that eventually became a part of the Standard are still present in boost. One of the classic examples of said above are smart pointers. So why do I need `Boost.SmartPtr` for the C++ compiler that supports C++11 and later?

Comment: People use Boost in production code so maintaining compatibility is a goal (of Boost).

Comment: Even the things that were absorbed still continue to evolve in boost (something the standard cannot permit to happen as rapidly). For example, `boost::enable_shared_from` is a type erasing alternative to `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @RichardCritten this is a good point I agree with it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that's a valuable point! also thought about it but did not have a good example

Comment: Also interesting is the more general question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851670/which-boost-features-overlap-with-c11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I need Boost.SmartPtr for the C++ compiler that supports C++11 and later?

Because:

1. You may need your program to compile with another compiler that doesn't support C++11 or later.
2. You may not want to bother implementing `make_unique` yourself. Sure it's easy, but why do it when you can use an existing implementation?
3. You may want to use one of the smart pointers provided by Boost.SmartPtr besides shared pointer.
4. You may already have been using it, and don't want to pay for the effort of stopping using it.

Comment: just for the reference to future readers `make_unique` is implemented in standard C++ starting from C++14

Comment: @eeroika can you please provide an example for #3?

Comment: @nickolay See the list of smart pointers in the documentation of Boost.SmartPtr.

Comment: thanks I understand that. Just thought you have a real world example on your fingertips. Such examples are always teaching!