# C++: Design objects to model unique items in a system

Tags: c++, design-patterns, modeling

I would like to model a group of items (people) where each individual has a set of unique characteristics... If I pass around my objects willy-nilly then copy constructors, etc. will cause my objects to diverge such that Object A will eventually have multiple different versions floating around, A` returned from method X, A`` returned from method Y and so forth. Which design pattern will help me ensure that if I pass around objects to various functions, that I'll be sure to always be acting on the unique representation of each given object. Thanks.

Comment: Just pass around smart pointers. 'nuff said

Comment: You can protect classes against being copied and enforce pointer/reference semantics, as mentioned.  Note also the existence of the convenience class [boost::noncopyable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823990/what-are-the-advantages-of-boostnoncopyable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use smart pointers or just pass by reference.  I'm not really sure what more advanced design pattern you're expecting to need.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, pointers, smart pointers, or pass-by-reference.

If you're worried about forgetting, you can make the copy constructor private.  That way, passing by value will be a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't make copies of your objects.  Store them all in a central location (using a container like std::vector or std::unordered_map) and then pass references to your various functions.  For example:

```
void MutatePerson( Person& object );
void InspectPerson( const Person& object );
```