# Return instance causes 'attempting to reference a deleted function' error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cdatabase

After working with C# for the past decade or two, my C++ is getting a little rusty.

I'm writing a database class and have an issue with the following method:

```
CRecordset CAccessDatabaseReader::ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery)
{
    CRecordset recordSet(&m_Database);
    recordSet.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, pszSqlQuery);
    return CRecordset(recordSet);
}
```

The compiler complains on the line with the `return` statement:

> Error C2280 'CRecordset::CRecordset(const CRecordset &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Can someone help me understand exactly what is happening here?

Comment: CRecordSet appears to be a non-copyable class. It does not have a copy constructor.

Comment: In C++, you can turn off copying of a class, and that is what CRecordset has done.  That's why you can't return it by value.

Comment: To "return" a CObject-based class like this you'll probably have to use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CRecordset`'s copy constructor has been explicitly marked as `deleted` to prevent copying `CRecordset` objects from one to the other.

So, the function will have to return a new object by pointer and require the caller to `delete` the object when finished using it:

```
CRecordset* CAccessDatabaseReader::ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery)
{
    CRecordset *recordSet = new CRecordset(&m_Database);
    if (!recordSet->Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, pszSqlQuery))
    {
        delete recordSet;
        return NULL; // or raise an exception
    }
    return recordSet;
}

CRecordset *rs = reader.ExecuteSqlQuery(TEXT("..."));
if (rs)
{
    ...
    delete rs;
}
```

Or better:

```
std::unique_ptr<CRecordset> CAccessDatabaseReader::ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery)
{
    std::unique_ptr<CRecordset> recordSet(new CRecordset(&m_Database));
    if (!recordSet->Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, pszSqlQuery))
        recordSet.reset(); // or raise an exception
    return recordSet;
}

std::unique_ptr<CRecordset> rs = reader.ExecuteSqlQuery(TEXT("..."));
if (rs)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the point of returning `std::unique_ptr<>`? Why not just return a regular pointer, and then have the caller assign that pointer to a variable of type `std::unique_ptr<>`? Isn't that simpler somehow?

Comment: And if the caller doesn't assign the raw pointer to a smart pointer class?  Then the caller risks a memory leak if it forgets to `delete` the pointer, or an uncaught exception occurs before it calls `delete`. The function has no way of knowing what the caller is or is not going to use. So better to be explicit about what memory management is expected. The whole point of using smart pointers is to avoid these kinds of issues. This also helps the function itself auto-manage the memory in case something goes wrong before `return` is called.

Answer (score 1):

`CRecordset` has deleted its copy constructor, so you cannot return it by value. You could possibly return a `std::unique_ptr<CRecordset>` or a  reference from `ExecuteSqlQuery` instead.

On deleting copy constructors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077164/2449857

On returning references from functions: [Is the practice of returning a C++ reference variable, evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/752658/2449857)

Comment: There is no "returning a reference" here

Comment: @M.M He said he's writing the `CAccessDatabaseReader` class. So he can make `ExecuteSqlQuery` return a `CRecordset&` or `const CRecordset&` if he does it right.

Comment: That would be a bad idea. The `unique_ptr` example in the answer on that thread might be useful though.