# Why does this return a copy of the drop_location?

Tags: c++

In the following code when I edit `drop_location.materials` it doesn't edit the drop_location that already exists in `prod_config`. Where is the found drop_location being copied, and how do I avoid the copy operate directly on the field in prod_config?

```
  auto prod_config = getProdConfig(nh);
  models::dropLocation_t drop_location;
  getDropLocationByName(prod_config, query_drop_location_name, drop_location);
  drop_location.materials = materials;
```

```
void getDropLocationByName(models::prod_t& prod_config, std::string query_drop_location_name, models::dropLocation_t& drop_location_out)
{
  auto& drop_locations = prod_config.dropLocations;
  auto it = std::find_if(
      drop_locations.begin(), drop_locations.end(), [&query_drop_location_name](auto drop_location) {
        return drop_location.name == query_drop_location_name;
      });
  if (it == drop_locations.end()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Drop location not found: " << query_drop_location_name;
    throw HTTP404Exception(ss.str());
  }
  drop_location_out = *it;
}
```

Comment: `T x = y;` makes `x` a copy of `y`.  Use `T&` to make `x` be an alias for `y`

Comment: @Lala5th preferably use `auto&`  (DRY principle)

Comment: You can also `delete` the copy constructor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077143/disable-copy-constructor and the compiler will tell you via an error where the copy is happening.

Comment: Which line is doing: `T x = y;`?

Comment: Try this: `auto& drop_locations = prod_config.dropLocations;` and we also need to change the functiom `getDropLocationByName` to return a reference type.

Comment: Okay, yeah that was definitely an issue, but I made the changes (reflected in the edit above), and still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: This is caused by drop_location is not a reference, so another copy happens, try to change the function into `models::dropLocation_t& getDropLocationByName(models::prod_t& prod_config, std::string query_drop_location_name)`

Comment: That worked. It seems it isn't possible with the outvar then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change existed values, we need to access then by reference or pointer. So a fixed code might like:

```cpp
auto prod_config = getProdConfig(nh);
try {
  auto& drop_location = getDropLocationByName(
      prod_config, query_drop_location_name, drop_location);
  drop_location.materials = materials;
} catch (...) {
}

models::dropLocation_t& getDropLocationByName(
    models::prod_t& prod_config, std::string query_drop_location_name) {
  auto& drop_locations = prod_config.dropLocations;
  auto it =
      std::find_if(drop_locations.begin(), drop_locations.end(),
                   [&query_drop_location_name](auto drop_location) {
                     return drop_location.name == query_drop_location_name;
                   });
  if (it == drop_locations.end()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Drop location not found: " << query_drop_location_name;
    throw HTTP404Exception(ss.str());
  }
  return *it;
}
```

Or via pointer:

```cpp
auto prod_config = getProdConfig(nh);
try {
  auto* drop_location = getDropLocationByName(
      prod_config, query_drop_location_name, drop_location);
  drop_location->materials = materials;
} catch (...) {
}
models::dropLocation_t* getDropLocationByName(
    models::prod_t& prod_config, std::string query_drop_location_name) {
  auto& drop_locations = prod_config.dropLocations;
  auto it =
      std::find_if(drop_locations.begin(), drop_locations.end(),
                   [&query_drop_location_name](auto drop_location) {
                     return drop_location.name == query_drop_location_name;
                   });
  if (it == drop_locations.end()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Drop location not found: " << query_drop_location_name;
    throw HTTP404Exception(ss.str());
  }
  return &*it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that it's being "copied", it's just that it's a completely independent object.

```
models::dropLocation_t drop_location;
```

This creates a completely independent, separate object, called `drop_location`.

Anything that's changed in this object, any member of this class instance that get modified, affects this object only. It will never have any effect on any other object that might exist somewhere.

```
 getDropLocationByName(prod_config, query_drop_location_name, drop_location);
 drop_location.materials = materials;
```

The effect of the function call appears to be to find some particular `models::dropLocation_t` instance that exists in `prod_config` and then copy it into `drop_location`. Ok, so something from `prod_config` was copied into `drop_location`. Great. Then `drop_location.materials` get modified. So far so good. The end result: some object from `prod_config` gets copied into `drop_location`, and then something else in `drop_location` called "material` gets modified.

And that's the end of the story. You seem to expect that just because that something was originally copied from `prod_config` into `drop_location` then this must mean that this modification affects the original object. That's approximately how objects might behave in Java or C#, but C++ is neither one of those two languages. Reduced into the most simple form, this is nothing more than:

```
 int c=0;

 int b=c;

 b=3;
```

`c` is still 0, only `b` gets changed to 3. Just because `b`'s value originally came from `c` doesn't mean that this also changes `c` to 3. The same thing applies to the shown code, as well. `drop_location.materials=materials;`, where `drop_location` is an object, only affects an object called `drop_location`, and no other object. The End. It does not affect anything else, and has no effect on whichever object the rest of `drop_location` may or may not have been copied from. `drop_location` is an independent object. It's not that its copied (and it was), it's just all objects in C++ are, well, discrete objects. In other languages, like Java, all objects are really pointers, so copying a so-called "object" from one place to another, and then modifying the "copied" object also ends up modifying the original "object", but that's not how objects work in C++.